# Kivy id: assignment

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

In Kivy you can dynamically assign a value to the widget id property from Python.  While it is possible to dynamically create widgets in Python I am unable to access those dynamically created widgets other attributes i.e update a **label.text** or retrieve a **text_input.text** property without the widget id **self.id.text**.

I am looking for a way to put an id="dynamic string property" in Python to allow later retrieval or changing of the widget property.  It appears user accessible widgets need to be explicitly defined in either Python or Kivy.

- in **Python**

> ```
> label1 = Label(text='test',...) # label1 becomes the property 
> self.label1.text = 'new value'
> ```

- in **Kivy**

> ```
> label1: label1
> Label:
>     id: label1
>     text: 'test'
> ```

Is there a another approach to access properties in dynamically created widgets?

I have tried passing the id to a function but the assignment operation as expected replaces the passed information.

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach explained in the [docs](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code):

Consider the code below in my.kv:

```
<MyFirstWidget>:
    # both these variables can be the same name and this doesn't lead to
    # an issue with uniqueness as the id is only accessible in kv.
    txt_inpt: txt_inpt
    Button:
        id: f_but
    TextInput:
        id: txt_inpt
        text: f_but.state
        on_text: root.check_status(f_but)
```

In myapp.py:

```
class MyFirstWidget(BoxLayout):

    txt_inpt = ObjectProperty(None)

    def check_status(self, btn):
        print('button state is: {state}'.format(state=btn.state))
        print('text input text is: {txt}'.format(txt=self.txt_inpt))
```